# _self is not working with a href

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am making a login form with a link if the user forgot password,
this form is inside div as below, but the problem is that when the user click `Forgot the password`, it opens this page in the whole page not on its div

```
<div>
<form class="form" method="POST" id="login-nav">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="emailaddress">Email address</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailaddress" name="emailaddress"placeholder="Email address" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="pwd">Password</label>
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="forgotpassword.php">Forgot the password ?</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <button type="submit" id="login_button" name="login_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**forgotpassword.php**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="emailaddress">Enter your email address</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="recovery_email" name="recovery_email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <button type="submit" id="resetpassword" name="resetpassword" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Reset Password</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what should be happening. It sounds like you're after something like an `<iframe>` if you want that sort of behaviour. Clicking on an `<a href="#">...</a>` will always "open in the whole page".

Comment: This is the normal behaviour - a link will open a new page, it won't update the contents of an element.

Comment: That's exactly the expected behavior; clicking a link will open the href in the current window, not some part of it. `<div>`s are used to structure HTML content. It sounds like you're confusing it with `<iframe>`. Edit: It should also be pointed out that your `<a>` doesn't actually contain `target="_self"`

Comment: u need to use js/jquery to load element in div or switch between hide and show

Comment: you can create a div having login form and another having forgot form and  nake forgot div  as display none by css and on the forgot button or link click u can triger on click event which will toggle the dispaly of both the div

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a modal popup or dialogue - have a google, there a re plenty of plugins that do it - I use fancybox2 for it

Answer (score 0):

_self is standard for the target-tag. It opens the link in the same browser window, just what you are describing.
DIVs are not iFrames. (And no one wants iFrames for something like this. Really.)

You have to build your div-structure again at your forgotpassword.php.